# Построение графиков с использованием SQL Server

Tags: javascript, html5, sql-server, flash

Добрый день!

Я пишу программы на языке VBA на MS Excel. В данное время на работе строю графики на MS Excel  из базы данных SQL Server. Графики на MS Excel получаются статичными, хотелось бы добавить интерактивности.

Вот, хотел с вами посоветоваться.

У меня есть база данных на SQL Server.
Хочу сделать приложение которое бы строила графики из базы данных SQL Server.
Пример графиков нашел в интернете, вот в таком виде интересует,

*http://www.highcharts.com/demo*

*http://www.flotcharts.org/flot/examples/interacting/index.html*

Есть одна проблема: невозможно поставить на работе веб-сервер(xampp, apache).

С помощью каких технологий можно написать такое приложение, можно в виде html, .exe файла.
Кто нибудь сталкивался с такой задачей?

Спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Что бы не уходить в дебри от родного VBA, можно попробовать в VB.NET генерировать нужный HTML и на компоненте WebBrowser его отображать... Ну или просто использовать VB.Net для нужных задач.

Comment: Хотелось бы сделать такой график чтобы пр наведении на точку показывал информацию о точке.